# Chart drawing fine on emulator but not on phone

Tags: android, drawing, android-canvas

I drew a basic Smith chart on the canvas using circles, arcs and lines. I have run the app on numerous size emulator screens and all work perfectly but once I tried it on an actual device (Android level 2.3.5) the chart does not line up as it should i.e. some objects are out of place.

While writing the code I was careful to use get.Width() and get.Height() for the parameters instead of using pixels so that the app would work correctly on all devices. Below is an example of the code i used:

```
canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()*1/2, canvas.getHeight()*3/8, canvas.getWidth()*475/1000, black);
        canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()*5/8, canvas.getWidth()*5/8, canvas.getWidth()*349/1000, black);
        canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()*6/8, canvas.getWidth()*5/8, canvas.getWidth()*228/1000, black);
        canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()*7/8, canvas.getWidth()*5/8, canvas.getWidth()*103/1000, black);
arc0.set(canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()*-139/700, canvas.getWidth()*100/69, canvas.getHeight()*3/8);   
        arc1.set(canvas.getWidth()*-6/112, canvas.getHeight()*-80/100, canvas.getWidth()*195/100, canvas.getHeight()*72/192);   
        arc2.set(canvas.getWidth()*7/10, canvas.getHeight()*70/700, canvas.getWidth()*125/100, canvas.getHeight()*3/8); 
        arc3.set(canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()*3/8, canvas.getWidth()*100/69, canvas.getHeight()*91/96);
        arc4.set(canvas.getWidth()*-8/112, canvas.getHeight()*3/8, canvas.getWidth()*195/100, canvas.getHeight()*150/100);
        arc5.set(canvas.getWidth()*7/10, canvas.getHeight()*3/8, canvas.getWidth()*125/100, canvas.getHeight()*65/100);
```

The graph lines up fine on all the different size emulator screens i have tried, so would anybody be able to tell me why it doesn't line up on an actual device. Thanks

Comment: try to draw a simple shape, if it works fine, there must be problem with the hard coded values, would you mind posting your code & xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use percentage values not numbers... moreover try to take a look on conversions of the value u r getting from getwidth(). Possibly some values are missing..

Comment: Thanks for the response. How would you use percentage values instead of numbers i was under the impression that you couldn't. Another solution i thought of was to use dp values but that did not work either.

Comment: hi when you said to use percentage values do you mean floats i.e. 0.50f instead of 1/2. Thanks